# onchange event is not fire on asp checkbox in chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This doesn't work for me in chrome

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFullReIndex" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="funCalled();" />

<script>
     function funCalled() {
        if ($('#chkFullReIndex')[0].checked) {
            alert('check box checked')
        }
        else {
           alert('check box not checked')
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is working perfectly fine in Firefox(21.0) but not working in chrome(Version 27.0.1453.94 m)am not getting any console error for the same

any thought on the same

Comment: @Zenith To get DOM element i think

Comment: did u check your html...is all braces close ??

Comment: @roasted Shouldn't there only be one element with that ID, so `$('#chkFullReIndex')` would be enough?

Comment: @Zenith Ya, but so it will be: $('#chkFullReIndex').is(':checked'). checked is a property of node element, not jquery object

Comment: @roasted I know, but his code doesn't look right. Mixing JS/jQuery like that isn't a great idea, better to use one or the other in this case

Comment: @Zenith completly agree

Comment: i had debug my script but it never hit my code that is my issue.. guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `onclick` event like

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkPostback" Text="Check me" onclick="javascript:funCalled(this)"
        ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Script

```
function funCalled(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
        alert('check box checked')
    } else {
        alert('check box not checked')
    }
}
```

[Check](http://forums.asp.net/t/1765202.aspx/1)

Answer (score 3):

When using inline event registration you can send `this` to the function:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkFullReIndex" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="funCalled(this);" />
```

and js like:

```
function funCalled(obj) {

    // this is present in the event handler and is sent to the function
    // obj now refers to the CheckBox, so we can do
    if (obj.checked) {
        alert('check box checked')
    } else {
        alert('check box not checked')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd take this approach since you're loading jQuery and barely using it.

```
$('#chkFullReIndex').on('change', function(e){
  var $this = ($this);
  if($this.is(':checked')){
    alert('It is checked!');
  } else {
    alert('It is not checked');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish cross browser functionality use this to check whether a checkbox is checked or not :-

```
$("#chkFullReIndex").is(':checked')
```

or

```
$("#chkFullReIndex").prop('checked')
```