# How do I disable an asp:CheckBox after it is checked and then execute server side code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net checkbox, which looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDoSomething" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="DoSomething"  />
```

As expected when I check the checkbox; the `DoSomething` method is called on the server side.  After the user has checked the checkbox; I want to disable it (so they cannot click it multiple times).

If I was using a button, then I could use OnClick and OnClientClick.  How can I do this with a Checkbox?

I have spent one hour Googling this and have looked here for example: [Enabling/disabling asp.net checkboxes through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644960/enabling-disabling-asp-net-checkboxes-through-javascript)

I cannot find an answer to my question.  Most questions I have read assume that you want to execute Javascript only and not both Javascript and server side code.

Update 1

He**re is th**e onchange method:

function Disable

```
Checkbox()
            {
                document.getElementById("chkDoSomething").disabled = true;
            }
```

**Update 2**

I have tried this:

```
 var chkDoSomething = document.getElementById("chkDoSomething");
    
                if (chkDoSomething != null) {
                    chkDoSomething.addEventListener('change', function () {
                        chkDoSomething.disabled = true;
                    });
                }
```

Still the Javascript blocks the post back.  As soon as I remove the Javascript, then the postback works.

Comment: You should just be able to write `onchange="someFunction();"` in the checkbox definition. That shouldn't stop the data being submitted to the server - have you tried it?

Comment: @ADyson, thanks.  Where do I put the call to the server side method (DoSomething()).

Comment: @w0051977 Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813589/311255

Comment: "Where do I put the call to the server side method"...where it already is now. Don't move it. `OnCheckedChanged="DoSomething"`, same as you've got already.

Comment: To be clear, are you experiencing a specific issue due to multiple clicking? What's the actual outcome you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @ADyson, I have added an onchange.  Now the client side function runs only.  How do I get the client side and server side function to both run?

Comment: what exactly does the onchange do? P.S. Can you answer my query about why exactly you're trying to do this at all

Comment: @ADyson, I have added an update to the question.  I think there is one line of code missing, which should be included at the end of the Javascript function (I think I have done this before), but can't remember what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable the CheckBox in the `CheckedChanged` event.

```
protected void chkDoSomething_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    cb.Enabled = false;
}
```

Update

A client side solution would be to wrap the CheckBox in a div and add `pointer-events:none` to it.

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDoSomething" runat="server"/>
</div>

<script>
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes but this won't be seen until the page is refreshed. I think OP wants to disable the checkbox as soon as it's clicked, to stop people clicking it on/off/on/off immediately

Comment: How do you associate the checkbox with this function?

Comment: @ADyson, yes but the page wil already be refreshed because the `OnCheckedChanged` and `AutoPostBack=true`. So there is no need for javascript.

Comment: @w0051977 what do you mean "associate"? You already are doing that `OnCheckedChanged="DoSomething"` > `protected void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @VDWWD it depends, if the network or server is a bit slow it can hang around on the same page for a second or two before it disappears. People often ask for similar functionality on form submit buttons, to stop multiple clicking (potentially resulting in multiple submissions)

Comment: @ADyson, ah, that is what you mean. But that won't work because if you disable the checkbox with `onclick="this.disabled=true"`, then the value won't be posted and the state will always be unchecked. But you could set it to display:none perhaps or some other trick.

Comment: @VDWWD that's true. Maybe a workaround is to put an absolutely positioned, transparent div over the top of the checkbox so it isn't clickable any more? I dunno. The OP hadn't got that far it would appear, their question seemed to be about how to have a client-side and server-side function both defined together.

Comment: @VDWWD, I am asking how to disable the checkbox on the client side before the post back is made (so that the user doesn't think they can check the checkbox multiple times).  Your server side function will return a new webpage with the checkbox disabled, which I certainly don't want.

Comment: @ADyson, found a trick. @ ws0051977 see the update.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Javascript instead of JQuery (see the tags in my original post).

Comment: That does not matter, just add `pointer-events:none` to the element above the checkbox with javascript.

Comment: It appears that you can only either call a client side function or a server side function (not both).

Comment: @w0051977 in native JS try using addEventListener to add the listener (instead of using onchange within the element). Then it won't overwrite any existing listeners (because actually in the background asp.net will actually be using a javascript event to trigger the call to the server when the checkbox is clicked, since there's no built-in way to submit a form when that happens). Hopefully that should ensure both methods work at once. And use WDWWD's workaround, so that outright disabling the element doesn't cause the value not to be submitted (as it would, per normal HTML form behaviour).

Comment: @ADyson, are you able to post this in your answer? I am Googling it now.

Comment: You cannot disable a checkbox. The value is not posted to the server. A "normal" javascript solution is to disable it and then enable them again on the submit button click. But since you use AutoPostBack this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same client-side solution as [VDWWD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918615/5947043) but written using native JS instead of jQuery, as you requested:

```
<script>
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        let div = this.closest("div");
        div.style.pointerEvents = "none";
      });
    }
</script>
```

As noted, this requires each affected checkbox to be wrapped inside a `<div>`.

Comment: I have tried something similar to that.  Event Listeners are stopping the postback as well.  Cannot believe howe difficult this is.

Comment: That's surprising, to be honest. Try my version, just to be sure. Then again, asp.net webforms was always a nightmare. But also ask yourself - is it really necessary? Are you seeing a definite problem arising from people clicking multiple times? If so, what is it? Maybe something can be done on the server side to mitigate the effects, instead.

Comment: Your code errors with this: "
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'"

Comment: @w0051977 what browser are you testing with? And what version? closest() is a newish function. You can check the compatibility table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest . There's also a polyfill provided if your browser doesn't support it.

Comment: @w0051977 Your update 2 won't work because, as we've said before, disabling the checkbox will mean that nothing is submitted to the server. You need to use the pointer-events version, which, if you use a supported browser (or the polyfill) does the job nicely from the client-side perspective - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8eptd2u1/ . (P.S. obviously you also need to remove any other "onchange" code in the element itself, or any other event listeners you've added, and use only this code.)

Comment: Your code works in Chrome i.e. it does not block the postback.  Thanks for that.  +1.  However, most my users are using IE! Is there something similar I can do for IE?

Comment: Like I said, use the polyfill provided in the documentation in order to emulate the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill . I don't envy you still having to support I.E. There are so many limitations (as you'd expect from something which stopped being actively developed years ago). We finally moved to Edge as the primary browser in my organisation last year. I.E. is only used for a couple of legacy 3rd-party sites.